# Loosing a list when i click a link

Tags: php, menu

I am going through a tutorial and I have a sidebar with 2 sections: category and brands. When I click any item within the brands list everything works fine but when I click any item within the category list, the brands just disappear from the page, can anyone help, please?

I am using the following code:

```
"<li><a href='index.php?brand=$brand_id'>$brand_title</a></li>";
```

This works fine, but when when I use this:

```
"<li><a href='index.php?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a></li>";
```

That's where I loose the brands list.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sorry but this is extremely short information to answer your question.

Comment: Hey, can you post more / complete code please.

Comment: im sorry i dont know if the code i have posted is displaying correctly is isnt for me and i dont know how to fix it sorry

Comment: echo "<li><a href='index.php?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a></li>"; thats the code that don't work

Comment: echo "<li><a href='index.php?brand=$brand_id'>$brand_title</a></li>"; yet if i use this code for the brands it works fine

Comment: @TonyFlowers What contains the four variables?

Comment: @TonyFlowers you could display the code correctly, when you copy paste it into the editor, mark the code and click on the brackets above the input field to higlight them as code

Answer (score 0):

From the Code out of the comment you should try this,

```
<?php
    echo "<li><a href='index.php?brand=" . $brand_id . "'>" . $brand_title . "</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='index.php?cat=" . $cat_id . "'>" . $cat_title . "</a></li>";
?>
```

EDIT:

```
function getBrands(){ 
    if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){ 
        global $connect; 
        $get_brands = "select * from brands"; 
        $run_brands = mysqli_query($connect, $get_brands); 
        while ($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){ 
            $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id']; 
            $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title']; 
            echo "<li><a href='index.php?brand=" . $brand_id . "'>" . $brand_title . "</a></li>"; 
        }
    }
}
```

So if you get a categorie the getBrands  function do nothing. remove the if  statement.

```
function getBrands(){ 
       global $connect; 
       $get_brands = "select * from brands"; 
       $run_brands = mysqli_query($connect, $get_brands); 
       while ($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){ 
            $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id']; 
            $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title']; 
            echo "<li><a href='index.php?brand=" . $brand_id . "'>" . $brand_title . "</a></li>"; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: using that code has the same result, the list just Disappears :-(

Comment: Whyy would this work better than the OP's code? It is the same, just a different method of string concatenation / use of variables in a string.

Comment: i had problems with the above code, when i use different charsets, we have no more information, about errors, or var dumps or anything else, so it was like searching in the fog

Comment: well have tried and no difference i'm afraid, im only a newbie but if im right im only pulling index.php as a template why would it display any different for the var? i thank everybody for there help btw :-) as a newbie its a bit daunting still :-(

Comment: @TonyFlowers Can you Post the complete index.php for us?

Comment: if it helps i have uploaded it onto my 1&1 account so u can view it online if its any easier to workout? if so its tonyflowers.co.uk/ecommerce/index.php

Comment: @TonyFlowers I mean the code, not a link to the file

Comment: yes of course sorry didnt know if was easier viewing the code source

Comment: On the Link we can only the the HTML Code with filled content, but the problem is the PHP code

Comment: <div class="content_wrapper">
                            <div id="sidebar">
                                        <div id="sidebar_title">Categories</div>
                    
                        <ul id="cats">
                            
                        <?php getCats (); ?>
                            
                        </ul>
                    
                    <div id="sidebar_title">Brands</div>
                    
                        <ul id="cats">
                        <?php getBrands (); ?>
                        </ul>
                </div>

Comment: thats the bit in index.php

Comment: function getBrands(){
    
    if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){

    global $connect;
    
    $get_brands = "select * from brands";
    $run_brands = mysqli_query($connect, $get_brands);
    
    while ($row_brands=mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){
        
        $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
        $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];
        
   
 echo "<li><a href='index.php?brand=" . $brand_id . "'>" . $brand_title . "</a></li>";

Comment: i'm really sorry but how do u get the code to display so nice lol

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Learn more…  Look @ "help" on the right side of the comments box

Comment: The problem should be this if `if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){ `

Comment: @TonyFlowers As a tip, if some ask you for more code, or details edit your Question, for other users its better to find that.

Comment: @TonyFlowers Do you removed the hole if Statement?

Comment: Just had to pop out, will be back in 10 mins and I will try it and let you know thank you for your help everyone